# is there any better solution to make a global configuration for exc_info and extra of logging

Tags: python, logging

The logging code like below will send all the log info to a remote server, and print them out in your terminal. The question here is, how to make a globle configuration like "basicConfig" does to simplify the code in each logger.

```
logger.error("Hey log it's an error", exc_info=True, extra=d)
```

For instance, I want to simplify the code above to logger.error("Hey log it's an error") with a default configuration of "exc_info=True, extra=d".

```
import logging
import threading
import time
import logging.handlers

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(pathname)s - %(filename)s - %(module)s - %(lineno)d  - %(process)d -  (%(threadName)-10s) - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
http_handler = logging.handlers.HTTPHandler(
    'ip:port',
    '/log',
    method='POST',
)
logger.addHandler(http_handler)

d = {'clientip': "your ip", 'user': 'logging_test'}

class ThreadUrl(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        logger.debug("Hey log it's a debug", extra=d)
        try:
            open('testfile')
        except Exception, e:
            logger.error("Hey log it's an error", exc_info=True, extra=d)


for i in range(10):
    t = ThreadUrl()
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The sample result in MongoDB.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58d1326215109901ce525da4"),
    "relativeCreated" : "9132.83205032",
    "process" : "57540",
    "CreateDate" : ISODate("2017-03-21T04:51:24.065+08:00"),
    "args" : "()",
    "module" : "Logging_inspect",
    "funcName" : "run",
    "user" : "logging_test",
    "exc_text" : "None",
    "clientip" : "your ip",
    "name" : "__main__",
    "thread" : "123145406930944",
    "created" : "1490076138.79",
    "threadName" : "Thread-10",
    "msecs" : "790.709972382",
    "filename" : "Logging_inspect.py",
    "levelno" : "40",
    "processName" : "MainProcess",
    "pathname" : "/Users/user/Desktop/Test/Test/Logging_inspect.py",
    "lineno" : "25",
    "msg" : "Hey log it's an error",
    "exc_info" : "(<type 'exceptions.IOError'>, IOError(2, 'No such file or directory'), <traceback object at 0x10419c248>)",
    "levelname" : "ERROR"
}
```

Comment: Why dont you create a your own logger class with a base class from `Logger` and then override the methods as required

Comment: @saurabhbaid you are right, but I feel confusing about how to override the methods. Could give me more hints about it? Thanks!

Comment: Little google can give you lots of tutotial on it like below one http://blog.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2014/05/19/method-overriding-in-python/#.WNDKdFWGOpo

Comment: @saurabhbaid Thanks! No need to override the Logger class. LoggerAdapter solved my problem,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoggerAdapter could solve it easily.

```
d = {'clientip': "your ip", 'user': 'logging_test'}
logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, d)
```